# Batch Script printing incremental numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some code below which is meant to help automate installing `choco` packages onto a `repo`.

However, instead of executing the command (which echos out correctly), all I get is a sequence of numbers starting from the number 1.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Code for reference:

```
@echo off 
set arr[0]=sts
set arr[1]=winscp 
set arr[2]=tortoisegit
set arr[3]=office2013pro  
set arr[4]=notepadplusplusandpm
set arr[5]=git
set arr[6]=GoogleChrome
set arr[7]=jdk
set arr[8]=maven
set "x=0"

:SymLoop  
if defined arr[%x%] (
    call set entry=%%arr[%x%]%%
    set command=choco install %entry% -y
    REM Command isn't running, just prints off numbers
    %command%
    set /a "x+=1"
    GOTO :SymLoop
)
```

Output is below:

> 123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119120121122123124125126127128129130131132133134135136137138139140141142143144145146147148149150151152153154155156157158159160161162163164165166167168169170171172173174175176177178179180181182183184185186187188189190191192193194195196197198199200201202203204205206207208209210211212213214215216217218219220221222223224225226227228229230231232233234235236237238239240241242243244245246247248249250251252253254255256257258259260261262263264265266267268269270271272273274275276277278279280281282283284285286287288289290291292293294295296297298299300301302303304305306307308309310311312313314315316317318319320321322323324325326327328329330331332

Comment: rather try with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) than with `CALL`. if you want to use `CALL` you should do it on each line and with doubled `%`. But this not only will make your code less readable but also will hit the performance.

Comment: Don't [double-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54324886)! Clarify your original question by editing it; if you do so well, it will be reopened.

Comment: I just closed your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54324886), because there wasn't any answer yet... perhaps it would be a good idea if you deleted it...

Comment: Anyway, I can't reproduce that; there is no command that outputs anything (like `echo`). Anyway, don't call the batch file `choco.bat`, since you have a tool with the same name. And for `%entry%` and `%command%`, you'll need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (so `!entry!` and `!command!`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set arr[0]=sts
set arr[1]=winscp
set arr[2]=tortoisegit
set arr[3]=office2013pro
set arr[4]=notepadplusplusandpm
set arr[5]=git
set arr[6]=GoogleChrome
set arr[7]=jdk
set arr[8]=maven
set "x=0"

:SymLoop
if not defined arr[%x%] goto :EndLoop
call set "entry=%%arr[%x%]%%"
set "command=choco install %entry% -y"
REM Command isn't running, just prints off numbers
%command%
set /a "x+=1"
GOTO :SymLoop
:EndLoop
```

Changing 2 lines and you can avoid the parentheses block of code.

This helps to avoid the need the delayed expansion. An example of requiring delayed expansion is shown in `set /?`.

> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
> ```

Everything between the parentheses is read as 1 block and evaluated once. So `%VAR%` within the parentheses does not change as it already has been substituted with the value.